# css margin-top is shoving down my footer

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a website and I divide them normally with a header, content and footer. When I want to add some more space between my content/login and my header I get some issues...

When I simply add `margin-top: 100px;` to `content` or `login`, it also shoves down my `footer`, I don't want that. How can I lower my `login` without shoving down my `footer`?

In this image you can see there is enough space in my content for the login to go down. [image]

```css
Body {
    margin: 0; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0098d9, #0098d9 49%, #ed1b24 49%);
    font-family: Verdana;
}
.MainDiv {
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    background-color: white;
}
.header {   
    text-align:center; 
    margin:0px auto;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 20%;          
}
.content {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 65%;
}
.footer {
    height: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.login {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #0098d9;
    border: 0.1em solid #0098d9;
    border-radius: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="menu">
    Menu:<br />
        <a href="Overview.php">Machine pages</a>
    </div>
    <div class="Maindiv">
        <div class="header">
            logo here    
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <form action="Index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="login">
                    <table class="loginTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2">Admin login</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="10px"><img class="icon" src="images/User.png"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username"</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img class="icon" src="images/locked.png"></td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan='2' align="right"><input type="submit" name="Login"  value="Login"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form> 
            <p class="errorMessage"><?php echo $message;?></p> 
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            Machinefabriek van de Weert B.V. <br />
            W: <a href="http://www.vandeweert.nl">www.vandeweert.nl</a><br />
            T: +31 (0)492-549 455
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Padding is your friend

Comment: When I use padding it does exactly the same, It shoves down my footer....

Comment: But I get it now... I just have to use a padding % and remove the % of my complete content so the page keeps the same %

Comment: I'll post an idea for you

Comment: Added a solution, let me know how you get on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to do 2 things:

Add this line to the top of your CSS: `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`.
It will make sure that the padding doesn't affect the height or width of your elements.

Then on `.content` add the `padding` you need, instead of `margin`. This will work for you :)

Comment: Ah that's what I needed! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

> Instead of margin give padding

Change css of .content class ...it will work

```css
 Body
 {
  margin: 0; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0098d9, #0098d9 49%, #ed1b24 49%);
  font-family: Verdana;
 }
 .MainDiv
 {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  background-color: white;
 }
 .header
 {   
  text-align:center; 
  margin:0px auto;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 20%;          
 }
 .content
 {
  padding : 25% ;
  height: 65%;
 }

 .footer
 {
  height: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
 }
 .login
 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: #0098d9;
  border: 0.1em solid #0098d9;
  border-radius: 1em;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="menu">
 Menu:<br />
  <a href="Overview.php">Machine pages</a>
 </div>
 <div class="Maindiv">
  <div class="header">
  logo here 
   
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <form action="Index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="login">
     <table class="loginTable">
      <tr>
       <td align="center" colspan="2">Admin login</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td width="10px"><img class="icon" src="images/User.png"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username"</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><img class="icon" src="images/locked.png"></td>
       <td><input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td colspan='2' align="right"><input type="submit" name="Login"  value="Login"></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </form> 
   <p class="errorMessage"><?php echo $message;?></p> 
   
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  Machinefabriek van de Weert B.V. <br />
  W: <a href="http://www.vandeweert.nl">www.vandeweert.nl</a><br />
  T: +31 (0)492-549 455
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: When I use padding on  content it still shoves down my footer... It's probably because I use %

Comment: You should prefer not to  use height in % ....only do if you give parent  div as in pixels...so give some specific height to Maindiv

Comment: I gave my Maindiv a minimumheight?

Answer (score 0):

Because you used a percent of the total height on each element. If you put a space before some of them, their height will remain, and the other elements will be pushed down.

You can use `padding` instead of `margin`, padding is inside the element and defines a space between the limit of the element and its content.

Comment: Even when I use padding on my content, it still shoves down my footer